# send and receive data in a https websrevice using soap in iOS - Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, soap, https

Currently I am getting error like "The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported." In below steps and I am using soap service to a HTTPS webservice.

```
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: What is the `media type` ?

Comment: for returndata nslog output like this: return data is <54686520 73657276 65722063 616e6e6f 74207365 72766963 65207468 65207265 71756573 74206265 63617573 65207468 65206d65 64696120 74797065 20697320 756e7375 70706f72 7465642e>

Comment: wen i try to add the contents from nsdata to nsstring i mean in this code:NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; nslog output is showing error like this: returnString The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported.

Comment: This means the service/url you are using is throwing the error not your code make sure you are making correct request.

Comment: Your error is telling you that your request was not created correctly. Show us how you created the request. Make sure you specify the `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers.

Comment: -(NSDictionary *)getResponseFromServerWithAction:(NSString *)Action SoapBody:(NSString*)SoapBody
{
  NSURL *locationOfWebService = [NSURL URLWithString:BaseURL];
   NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:locationOfWebService];
  NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[SoapBody length]];
   NSString* mainAction=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tempuri.org/IService/%@",Action];

Comment: [request addValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:mainAction forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [request addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    //the below encoding is used to send data over the net
    [request setHTTPBody:[SoapBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

Comment: NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
     if([returnString isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        return nil;
    }else
    {
      
        NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLData:returnData];
        
          NSLog(@"xml dic is %@",xmlDictionary);
        return xmlDictionary;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had resolved this issue by binding HTTPS with HTTP. Now i can access the same webservice with SOAP.